# Сорокин птенец или птенец сороки?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Правильно ли будет если написать *сорокин птенец, воронин птенец,* как например Татьянин день? Или возможно только *птенец сороки, вороны?*

Answer (score 1):

Возможно: *сорочий, вороний птенец*. А «сорокин» и «воронин птенец» — ошибка.

Answer (score 1):

[**сорочий**](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B9), сорочья, сорочье. *Прил.* к сорока.
1. Сорочьи яйца. Сорочий глаз (название растения).

*Крыша прутяная, как само гнездо. Вероятно, она служит защитой не от дождя, а от каких-нибудь непрошеных гостей, готовых полакомиться **сорочьими яйцами или птенцами*** (В. Солоухин).

[**вороний**](http://www.%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B0.%D1%80%D1%84/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8/%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0), -ья, -ье. Воронье гнездо. Воронья стая. Вороний глаз.
*Ворона каркнула во всё **воронье горло*** (Крылов).

*Года четыре назад мне потребовалось проследить, как растут в гнезде **вороньи птенцы*** (А. Барановский).

[Ворон и ворона](http://rus.1sep.ru/article.php?ID=200100503)

Answer (score 1):

Такое возможно лишь в случаях, когда выражение относят к *конкретной* сороке (например, в качестве литературного персонажа), но не к биологическому виду (только "сорочий"). У Даля в статье "Сорока" приводится "***сорокино*** гнездо". Нет проблем в случае, если Сорока - прозвище (у Серафимовича в одном из рассказов, 1905, находим: "Сорокина добыча").

Comment: Как же с «ворониным птенцом»? Аналогично? (В ответе ни слова...)

Comment: Да. Это обычная притяжательность при обозначении "собственности". Если это Ваша домашняя ворона, то назвать её птенца "вороньим" было бы проявлением пренебрежения к собственной питомице. _Воронье горло_ у Крылова не только от этого, но и ввиду ссылки на свойственную всем воронам физиологию. Для сравнения ситуаций - история с потерявшейся и нашедшейся ручной вороной, где _барышня гладила воронин клюв_: http://poteryashka.spb.ru/board/15-1-0-55507 Иной вариант фразеологии в этой ситуации напоминал бы "расчленёнку".

Comment: Да. Как и «сорочьи яйца» из ответа Niemand. «В ответе ни слова» — это просьба дополнить ответ. Этот  Ваш комментарий может и дополнить, и украсить.